# Wi-Fi Aware scan throttling

Tags: android, android-wifi

Google introduced a set of limitations in Android 8 or 9 regarding Wi-Fi scanning frequency. Apps are restricted in how frequently they're able to scan for Wi-Fi connections, including P2P Wi-Fi peers. What is the situation with Wi-Fi Aware? Does it have the same limitation? Is it easier to bypass it?

Comment: One quick question. Why do you need to explicitly request scans so frequently? Don't the intents like [PEERS_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager#WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION) suffice?

Comment: @Zoso I am thinking about high-frequency way of getting the Wi-Fi RSSI between two devices in order to determine the angle between them as inspired by this http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~huangwc/papers/2016-UBICOMP-WalkieLokie.pdf paper.

Comment: The idea is that I would use RSSI instead of sound strength.

Comment: Got your use case. Could you tell which API are you referring to for the requests(which you suspect might be throttled)? Is it the [requestNetwork()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#requestNetwork(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)) API?

Comment: I don't have any API in mind (yet). I just noticed that Android limited WiFi scanning. I think that the question is should ask is rather of a way to get high-frequency RSSI between two P2P Android smartphones. Do you have anything in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is as per the latest comments by OP.

One way to keep track of the RSSI of the network is to register for the intent [RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION) using a `BroadcastReceiver` and then extract the raw RSSI values from the Intent's extra values which are stored with the key [Wi-FiManager.EXTRA_NEW_RSSI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#EXTRA_NEW_RSSI) and obtain the threshold levels(*usually* the workable values) using [calculateSignalLevel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#calculateSignalLevel(int)). Some approximate code:

```
    } else if (action.equals(WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
        // Default to -200 as its below WifiManager.MIN_RSSI.
        int rawRssi = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NEW_RSSI, -200);
        int rssiLevel = mWifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rawRssi);
    }
```

Also, to answer the previous question as to whether Wi-Fi aware is restricted by the same scan restrictions, the answer is 'no', not because it has a waiver vis-a-vis Wi-Fi-Direct but because it operates differently from a Wi-Fi-Direct connection. For a Wi-Fi Direct connection, one needs to make a `request()` to the `WifiManager` for initiating a scan and it is these scans that are throttled, with the duration of throttling varying based on whether the app is in foreground/background. This throttling can of course be overridden from the Developer Settings page.

Wi-Fi-Aware works with a different paradigm. If this is regarding the usage of ranging, then one can leverage Wi-Fi-Aware technology between two devices as follows:

1. Check whether ranging is supported using Wi-Fi-RTTI apis using    `context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI_RTT);`
2. Check whether Wi-Fi RTT is available by registering for the intent    `WifiRttManager.ACTION_WIFI_RTT_STATE_CHANGED` and on its receipt, check for whether Wi-Fi RTT is available.
3. Create a [ranging request](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/rtt/RangingRequest)
4. Start [ranging](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/rtt/WifiRttManager#startRanging(android.net.wifi.rtt.RangingRequest,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20android.net.wifi.rtt.RangingResultCallback))
5. Extract [rssi](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-rtt#get-results) from a successful ranging result.

One thing to note is that the requests for ranging are limited to 20 from each UID as per [this](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/modules/Wifi/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/rtt/RttServiceImpl.java;l=110;drc=master;bpv=0;bpt=1) code from the framework.

```
static final int MAX_QUEUED_PER_UID = 20;
```

Note that if you're running as a regular application, your app would have its own UID.